# Printer printing in inverted colors

Tags: 20.04, printing, colors

I have a Canon g30-10 inkjet printer. Whenever I print something, the printed paper is a color inverted version of the file. For example, if i print a simple word document with black text on white background, printer prints white text over black background, and litterally covers the whole paper with ink except where the text is. How to fix this? IS there a fix? (Tried downloading some generic canon printer drivers- as explained here:https://itsubuntu.com/how-to-install-canon-printer-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04/) didnn't change anything- a reboot also does not fix it.
Canon g30-10
Ubuntu 20.04
Printer connected through wifi, no USB cable.